# How to Root Android Studio Emulator in mac (3.2.1 Version)

Tags: android-emulator

All,

For Infosec review I have to test my Andriod application in a Rooted Device, So I want to Root my Andriod Studio(3.2.1), Emulator and test my App, What is the process to ROOT Emulator on Mac, I have seen few links but links to download the resources are not working(I tried NOX it is fine But want to test in Android Studio Emulator).

Comment: NOX is also using the same system image that is in android emulator. So why you want to forcibly test your application in the android emulator. Android Emulator, NOX, BlueStack all are the same because they use the same system image.

Comment: @Heisenberg All of them use a generic image, but it is a specific version (since macOS does not support changing images like NOX on PC). You have to build and install the app manually because there is no Android Studio integration. The macOS versions are also extremely crippled compared to the PC builds. There are hundreds of reasons why your statement is invalid or inaccurate.